# How can I debug Java errors?

Tags: java, json, vb.net

I'm writing an application to launch Minecraft with mods, and will also keep the mods up-to-date. I'm getting a JVM error that I can't seem to fix.

I've been searching on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow for answers and can't find anything useful on Google. I'm actually basing my code off of another question I found on this site, but it was missing a lot of important information.

What is this error caused by? Is it a problem with my code? Is there any way to fix it?

EDIT: Is it possible to get the output of the JVM? I need more information for debugging.

Here is my VB.NET code.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader
    Dim Root As String = "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"
    Dim SelectedGameVersion As String = "1.10"
    Dim MinecraftJavaPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe"
    Dim JavaPath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe"
    Dim FileList As New ArrayList

    Dim assets As String = "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\index\1.10.json"

    Dim MinMemAlloc As String = "1G"
    Dim MaxMemAlloc As String = "4G"
    Dim mainClass As String = "net.minecraft.client.main.Main"

    Dim accessToken As String = "INVALID"
    Dim id As String = "INVALID"
    Dim username As String = "INVALID"
    Dim legacy As Boolean = False

    Dim debugString As String = ""

    Dim LIBRARIES As String = Root + "\versions\1.10.2\1.10.2-natives"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            'debugString = "UUID: " + id + ", Username: " + username + ", Legacy?: " + legacy.ToString

            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\vecmath-1.5.2.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.24\authlib-1.5.24.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.6\realms-1.10.6.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar;") ' UPDATED
            FileList.Add("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar;") ' UPDATED
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Oh noes!")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub authRequest()
        Try
            Dim status As HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed
            Dim response As Byte() = PostResponse("http://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate", "{""agent"": {""name"": ""Minecraft"",""version"": 1},""username"": " + txtUsername.Text + ",""password"": " + txtPassword.Text + "}", status)
            Dim responseString As String
            responseString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response)
            responseString = "NULL"
            Console.WriteLine("Response Code: " & status)
            Console.WriteLine("Response String: " & responseString)

            Dim json As String = responseString
            Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
            Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

            For Each item As JProperty In data
                item.CreateReader()
                Select Case item.Name
                    Case "availableProfiles"
                        For Each profileVar As JObject In item.Values
                            id = profileVar("id")
                            username = profileVar("name")
                            legacy = profileVar("legacy")
                        Next
                    Case ""
                        For Each profileVar As Object In item.Values
                            accessToken = profileVar("accessToken")
                            'MsgBox(profileVar("accessToken"), , "Debug")
                        Next
                End Select
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Oh noes!")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub launchGame()
        Try
            If Not File.Exists(Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar") Then
                MsgBox("File not found: " + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar")
            Else

                Dim Gamelibraries As String = Nothing
                For i = 0 To FileList.Count - 1
                    Gamelibraries += FileList.Item(i) +
                    Environment.NewLine()
                Next


                Dim p As New Process()
                p.StartInfo.FileName = JavaPath
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -Xms" + MinMemAlloc + "M -Xmx" + MaxMemAlloc + "M " +
                    "-Djava.library.path=" + LIBRARIES + "-natives -cp " +
                    Gamelibraries.ToString() + mainClass +
                    " --username=" + username +
                    " --version " + SelectedGameVersion +
                    " --gameDir " + Root +
                    " --assetsDir " + Root + "\assets" +
                    " --assetIndex 1.10" +
                    " --accessToken " + accessToken +
                    " --userProperties {}" +
                    " --userType mojang" +
                    " --uuid " + id +
                    " --nativeLauncherVersion 307"
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Root
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
                Application.DoEvents()
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                'AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf p_OutputDataReceived
                'AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf p.OutputDataReceived
                p.Start()
                p.BeginErrorReadLine()
                p.BeginOutputReadLine()
                'Button1.Text = "Play"
                'Button1.Enabled = True
                'Button2.Enabled = True
                'Button3.Enabled = True
                'Button4.Enabled = True
                'Button5.Enabled = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Oh noes!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Try
            authRequest()
            'Thread.Sleep(3000)
            'MsgBox(debugString, , "Debug")
            launchGame()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Oh noes!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function PostResponse(url As String, content As String, ByRef statusCode As HttpStatusCode) As Byte()
        Dim responseFromServer As Byte() = Nothing
        Dim dataStream As Stream = Nothing
        Try
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
            request.Timeout = 120000
            request.Method = "POST"
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim thisRead As Integer = 0
            Dim buff As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
            Do
                thisRead = dataStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)
                If thisRead = 0 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                ms.Write(buff, 0, thisRead)
            Loop While True
            responseFromServer = ms.ToArray()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        Catch ex As WebException
            If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
                dataStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
                Dim resp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                statusCode = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
            Else
                Dim resp As String = ""
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed
        End Try
        Return responseFromServer
    End Function

End Class
```

NOTE: I'm very new to JSON, so if you could point out if there's something wrong with it that would help me with my project a lot.

Comment: And what is that JVM error? Or is that a secret?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's late for me, I didn't realize I didn't include the error. The error is: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Add the stack trace to your question please.

Comment: Print `p.StartInfo.Arguments`, and try to launch Java manually with these arguments. If the error comes again, you have to adjust the arguments and after that modify the code.

Comment: There wasn't a stacktrace, just that message window from the JVM. That's all it's giving me. I would probably be able to understand it better myself if it gave me a stacktrace.

Comment: Then I am with aubin: avoid the vb layer and try if running this manually gives more of a clue.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't get back to you on that. I tried running it manually and it just opened the same message window. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.